# upload file in cakephp without pluggin or using controller code

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.1

I am learning CakePHP 2.0, and created a sample test application, where user can submit a file at the time of registration.

below is the database table

### users   Table

```
id Auto_Increment
first_name
last_name
email
doc_file
```

And also created `User.php` and `UsersController.php`

and below are the content code in `UsersController.php`

### UsersController.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController{

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');


    public function index(){
        $this->set('user1', $this->User->find('all'));
    }


    public function register(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                //move_uploaded_file($this->data['Model']['field']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.DS.'xxx');

                move_uploaded_file($this->data['User']['doc_file']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.DS.'hello.doc');

                $this->Session->setFlash('User is created');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Cannot register a user');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in Views, I have created a two files ie `index.ctp` and `register.ctp` with a directory `Users` in View directory

code content of `register.ctp`

### register.ctp

```
<?php

    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('label'=>'First Name'));
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('label'=>'Last Name'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('doc_file', array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Register');
?>
```

And when run this page, and fill up all information, it gives an error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
```

And below is the query I got, where it is inserting an `array` into `doc_file`

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `database_db`.`users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `doc_file`) VALUES ('master', 'shifu', 'shifu@k.com', Array)
```

What i am trying :

While user is registering, the file name should be random and it should be move to

`localhost/mysite/app/webroot/files/user_data/` or
`localhost/mysite/app/webroot/files/user_data/user_id_directory/`

its good, if it creates the userid directory and storing the file in its parent user directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that CakePHP is seeing the doc_file field and trying to insert it into the database.

After Cake has processed the form submission, doc_file contains an array of values.

You can fix it by doing the following:

In your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('new_doc_file', array('type'=>'file'));
```

In your controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')){
    $this->data['User']['doc_file'] = WWW_ROOT.DS.'hello.doc';
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
        move_uploaded_file($this->data['User']['new_doc_file']['tmp_name'], $this->data['User']['doc_file']);

        $this->Session->setFlash('User is created');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Cannot register a user');
    }
}
```

(ie. upload the file with a temporary field name, manually add the doc_file field to the post array before you try to save).

Comment: see this statement `$this->User->save($this->request->data)` is storing values into database... 

I got the uploading of file , but how can the name be inserted into database table. And when saving, its giving an error ie `Database Error` ie an `Array` cannot be inserted into `table` field right..

We need a single value from that `Array`.

Comment: @RicharAtHome can you let me know, how to manually add the doc_file field to the post array before you try to save

Comment: I'm manually adding the doc_file field to the post array with this line: $this->data['User']['doc_file'] = WWW_ROOT.DS.'hello.doc';

Comment: Then use some simple regex or string slicing to extract the name from the new_doc_file field :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that

```
$this->data['User']['doc_file']['tmp_name']
```

is returning an array - try

```
debug($this->data['User']['doc_file']['tmp_name'])
```

in your controller code to see what it contains.

Comment: Its returning something like this `D:\xampp\tmp\phpF639.tmp` and `\app\Controller\UsersController.php (line 19)`